# В чём ошибка? argv

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Учу `Python` по книге. И не понимаю, в чём ошибка. В книге указано, что если выдаёт ошибку, как в моём случае, то я дал 3 значения, а не 4, но, я дал 4.

***Код:***

```py
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv
print("1:", script)
print("2:", first)
print("3:", second)
print("4:", third)
```

***Вывод консоли:***

[image: Вывод консоли1]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что мат в вопросах это уже совсем как-то

Comment: А что не так? Матом я выражаю всю свою заинтересованность и негодование по этому вопросу.

Comment: @ИлонМаск то есть по вопросу собственной неспособности понять печатный текст?

Answer (score 2):

Первым аргументом передаётся название скрипта, поэтому пользовательских аргументов ожидается всего 3.

***Консоль:***

```py
python test.py spam bacon eggs
```

***stdout:***

```py
1: test.py
2: spam
3: bacon
4: eggs
```

Comment: @ИлонМаск Рад помочь. Если ответ помог, Вы можете отметить его как верный, нажав на галочку слева. От себя хочу попросить Вас быть менее эмоциональным. Мат в сообщениях и код картинкой сильно отпугивают отвечающих. Если бы Вы правильно оформили вопрос, то можно было бы избежать такого большого количества минусов.

Comment: Ответ верный нажал. Матом я МАКСИМАЛЬНО подробно опишу ситуацию, чтобы пользователи внятно могли мне помочь. И я мат использую грамотно, там где он как раз таки нужен. Насчёт картинки тоже не вижу ничего плохого. Да, мог и в печатном виде как код, но картинкой тоже всё понятно. Весь код хорошо видно, да и ошибку тоже.

Comment: @ИлонМаск Приводить код текстом стоит, чтобы его могли как минимум скопировать и запустить. Также это влияет на индексирование страницы в интернете. А насчёт мата... лично я считаю, что он не добавляет смысловой нагрузки к тексту, только эмоции.

Comment: Матом я выражаю всю свою заинтересованность и негодование по этому вопросу. Бессмысленно отрицать его. Мат красивый, это уже часть нашей культуры. И не надо этого стыдиться.
Насчёт кода понял, ну да, мог бы и перевести.

Comment: Матом я выражаю всю свою заинтересованность и негодование по этому вопросу. Бессмысленно отрицать его. Мат красивый, это уже часть нашей культуры. И не надо этого стыдиться.
Насчёт кода понял, ну да, мог бы и перевести.